# C# Book Question

Tags: c#

This is a question regarding following books.

1)  Effective C# -  Edition 1

2)  More Effective C#

3)  Effective C# - Edition  2

Is it progressive i.e., the third one contains contents of 1 and 2. Second one contains contents of 1 – like that? Or each content is entirely different?

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 4):

Effective C# and [More Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321485890) are two different books. They both cover how to solved various problems in an efficient way. If you enjoy one you'll probably enjoy the other as well.

The descriptions on e.g. Amazon contain lots about what each book covers.

I am not aware of a volume 1 and 2 of Effective C#, but I believe there's an updated [second edition of Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321658701) if that is what you're referring to.

Comment: Please see the linked descriptions on Amazon. They are quite elaborate.

Comment: When looking at Amazon, note that Effective C# 1st ed was strangely *full* of typographical and layout errors. I only have the 2nd ed, and it's really been cleaned up.